# Qt 5.3. Painting on QOpenGLFrameBuffer

Tags: qt, opengl, qt5, framebuffer

Painting on a QOpenGLFrameBuffer in the Qt 5.3 (beta) seems a bit elusive to me I can get only a black image. (I Haven't tried previous versions of Qt5 but haven't find any notice of some problem in this area)

Searching around I've copied the exact sample at http://dangelog.wordpress.com/2013/02/10/using-fbos-instead-of-pbuffers-in-qt-5-2.

Adding just before the end of createImageWIthFBO()

```
  QImage img=fbo.toImage();
  img.save("d:/tmp.jpg");
```

to inspect the fresh result with no further operations but the resulting image is black.

Am I missing something? perhaps some platform problem? (Win 8.0 here)

Comment: it's beta. did you tried ask on qt forum in beta thread?

Comment: As the author of that code, I can confirm it works properly on Linux/NVIDIA with 5.2.1, 5.3 RC and 5.4 (i.e. dev branch). Does the snippet copied as-is work as expected? Which GPU do you have? Given it was written for 5.0, did you try modifying it by using a `QOffscreenSurface` (added in 5.1) instead of an invisible QWindow?

Comment: Thanks for checking peppe. The GPU is NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M. I am trying the snipped copied as is only adding the two lines I menctioned to save the image, this is what is giving the resulting black image. I've just tried also with a QOffscreenSurface with the same result. It has to be some stupid detail....

Comment: But if you *don't* modify it, are you able to see it draw as expected? I'm just trying to bisect a problem with the FBO vs. a problem with the image save.

Comment: I got it! The problem was in format.setMajorVersion(3); , it must be 2. I tried it in Android and it was failing wen creating the context. Next changing to use a QOffscreenSurface and it worked because I got the format from the surface itself. Now with the QWindow it also works on my Android phone.

Comment: For what is worth the native painting does nothing in Android, didn investigate further. (the Android is a Galaxy Nexus 4 phone Android 4.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the instruction `format.setMajorVersion(3)`, that 3 should be a 2 and all works as expected. (I guess some implementations of opengl are more picky in this detail)